# How to convert exponential value into float

Tags: mysql, performance, types, mapping

my source is mysql and datatype is double and value is 0.00000000000000177635683940025.
my target is sql server and datatype is float and value is 1.77635683940025E-15.
Now I want to cast/convert back into original value but did not find proper way.
I would really appreciate if anyone could help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: so, it happens in (ms) sql server?

Comment: Converting from double to float loses precision that cannot be regained by converting back.  Dump the hex values; we may be able to discuss this further.

Comment: SQL Server is a different product than MySQL.  If you are using both, have both tags.  If you are using only MySQL, fix the terminology in the Question.